# How do I filter out MIMETYPE in Google Drive Activity API

Tags: google-apps-activity

I'm working on a project that uses the Google API in Javascript.
It uses the Google Drive Activity API (Not the Google Drive API!!!)

I want to filter out all the folders from the results, is this possible?

Here is what my code looks like:

`gapi.client.driveactivity.activity.query( {"pageSize": 10 }).then((response) => { console.log(response) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Using request parameters only, it is not possible to filter returned information, such as removing results pertaining to folders, using the Drive Activity API alone.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on the [`activity.query` method](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query?), there is information about the `filter` field, which allows the response to be filtered based on certain parameters.

The only available filter parameters, however, are `time` and `detail.action_detail_case`:

> | Fields |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | `filter` | `string` The filtering for items returned from this query request. The format of the filter string is a sequence of expressions, joined by an optional "AND", where each expression is of the form "field operator value". Supported fields: • `time`: Uses numerical operators on date values either in terms of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 or in RFC 3339 format. Examples: • `time > 1452409200000 AND time <= 1492812924310` • `time >= "2016-01-10T01:02:03-05:00"` • `detail.action_detail_case`: Uses the "has" operator (:) and either a singular value or a list of allowed action types enclosed in parentheses. Examples: • `detail.action_detail_case: RENAME` • `detail.action_detail_case:(CREATE EDIT)` • `-detail.action_detail_case:MOVE` |

In this case, you would have to write a script to remove folder activity from the response, locally.

Comment: I thought that might've been the case, I'll implement that then, thanks for the reply